# Use SmartCard to "Log on as" in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, smartcard

I have developed a Windows Service (using C#, for note) that must be running under a user account (not Local or Network), however in my company there is a policy that requires that user must be logged in with SmartCard.

When I try to start the service with regular authentication the error was raised with "SmartCard logon required" message. However I can not see any option to authenticate with it.

Can someone help me with that?

**PS:** Remove the SmartCard policy is out of question.

Comment: What account is the service running under?

Comment: I think I don't understand your question, but there it goes: I have developed the WinSvc and it should run under certain SmartCard credentials but I am not being able to authenticate with it.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed you clearly said it must run under a user account.